# Recursive Relationships in SQL Database

Tags: sql

I have a database designed on the  Entity Relationship Model which is for a train booking system.

The database contains primary keys and foreign key constraints, and several one to many and many to many relationships.

I'm having difficulty understanding recursive relationships. Can anyone please explain how I would identify a recursive relationship in a database?

Answer (score 0):

A recursive relationship would usually be expressed as a foreign key relationship back to the same table.

For instance, if you had a file system with folders, then folders contain folders, and you might. have:

```
create table folders (
    folder_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    parent_folder_id int,
    constraint fk_folder_parent foreign key (parent_folder_id) references folders(folder_id)
);
```

Note:  The constraint *represents* the hierarchical relationship in the database, but it does not "create" it.  The relationship is part of the logical definition of the entities.